# Ubuntu Single Sign-On Account stuck on "Connecting..."

Tags: single-sign-on

Hi I've just installed Ubuntu 18.04
When I go to settings / online accounts and click Ubuntu Single Sing-ON and input the correct credentials it just hangs on "Connecting..." and doesn't do anything. If I put incorrect details in however It almost immediately tells me that the credentials are incorrect. Is this a bug or me being silly and is there a work around?

Thanks For any help.

Comment: I'm having the same issue myself. I've checked logging in from the browser as well, no problem. Other accounts sign in fine.

Answer (score 5):

Try removing any existing Ubuntu accounts and adding them again. That simple step worked for me.

You should be getting a message about authorising the snap daemon (which asks for your local root user password). If not, check if snap works:

```
snap login
```

If you don't have snap, there might be something wrong with your Ubuntu (it should be included by default). Snap *can*, however, be installed:

```
sudo apt install snapd
```

If you still cannot add your account, but you only wanted to enable canonical-livepatch, try activating it from terminal:

```
sudo snap install canonical-livepatch
sudo canonical-livepatch enable <key>
```

replace < key >  with your live-patch key, which can be generated from:
https://www.ubuntu.com/livepatch

Then go open 'software & updates', click on the 'updates' tab, and enable livepatch

Answer (score 1):

With 20.04, I found that [the livepatch URL](https://www.ubuntu.com/livepatch) above redirects to Ubuntu Advantage and that when you click the green button "Get Ubuntu Advantage" then you can create a free key but the command to enable livepatch is different:

```
sudo ua attach <key>
```

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks.