# Stuck on Ubuntu Single Sign-On Account

Tags: 20.04, system-installation, online-accounts, canonical-livepatch, single-sign-on

I made a fresh Ubuntu Installation and got stuck on the Ubuntu Single Sign-On Account. It's not able to SignIn neither it's getting cancelled, It's very much irritating. What can be done in this case? Is this any new bug from Ubuntu?
[image]

Comment: You should probably report this bug, annoying as it is! You can try right-clicking the Ubuntu logo in the left dock and clicking 'Quit'. Alternatively, from a terminal, run `killall gnome-initial-setup`.

Comment: @can't report without SignIn

Comment: Even using `apport` from a terminal?

Comment: Thanks, No idea how much time will the ubuntu will take to fix this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu Single Sign-On Account stuck on "Connecting..."](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1069356/ubuntu-single-sign-on-account-stuck-on-connecting)

Comment: @zwets I tried this out, Nothing happened.