# Ubuntu 20.04.3 stuck on trying to connect on Ubuntu Single Sign on

Tags: single-sign-on

1. Installed Ubuntu as virtual machine.
2. Registered my Ubuntu SSO Account
3. After booting and asking me to login in with correct credentials -
   Nothing happens
   See attached screenshot.
   NB: (With incorrect credentials - user is prompted to change entry)

I see others have a similar issue : [Ubuntu Single Sign-On Account stuck on "Connecting..."](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1069356/ubuntu-single-sign-on-account-stuck-on-connecting)

[SSO Stuck image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7Ri4.png)

Comment: Your own link suggests a fix. Have you tried it? Results? If not then why not?