# Ubuntu single sign-on account stuck on "Connecting"

Tags: 20.04, online-accounts, single-sign-on

I've just installed Ubuntu 20.04. When I go to Settings → *Online Accounts*  → *Ubuntu Single Sign-On* and input the correct credentials, it just hangs on *Connecting...* and doesn't do anything. However, if I enter incorrect details, it almost immediately tells me that the credentials are incorrect.

Here is a screenshot of Ubuntu SSO stuck on *Connecting...*:

[image: Screenshot of Ubuntu SSO stuck on "Connecting..."]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu Single Sign-On Account stuck on "Connecting..."](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1069356/ubuntu-single-sign-on-account-stuck-on-connecting)

Comment: Thanks to that topic I've enabled livepatch. But I still can't add an 'Ubuntu Single Sing-On'. And I saw that topic before I created this one.
Can you tell me: do I need this authentication for anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies for the trouble. We traced this issue to a secondary service the Online Account panel talks to, in the process of setting up the Ubuntu SSO account (it's not directly SSO which is why it took us a little while to pinpoint the problem). It'll be fixed in the next 30 minutes.