# Ubuntu 22.04 Single Sign-on account is stuck on "Connecting..."

Tags: 22.04, online-accounts, single-sign-on

I've just reinstalled Ubuntu 22.04. When I go to Settings / Online accounts and click Ubuntu Single Sign-on and input the correct credentials it just hangs on "Connecting..." and doesn't do anything. If I put incorrect details in however it almost immediately tells me that the credentials are incorrect, but I can sign in to the web. I tried it with another account, and it's the same. I tried it from another machine, and it's not working there either.

Previously I had signed on in this same procedure, and it was working.

I tried this one, but I can just sign in for Livepatch.[Ubuntu Single Sign-On Account stuck on "Connecting..."](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1069356/ubuntu-single-sign-on-account-stuck-on-connecting)

Running Settings from terminal, after few seconds of correct credential input, I got this error in the terminal: [(gnome-control-center:2710): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 00:02:45.504: g_task_return_error: assertion 'error != NULL' failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKnwO.png)